# Dropdown list to filter gridview

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, filter, drop-down-menu

I would like my gridview to be filtered by the dropdown list I have. It is pulling specific information from the database, so when you choose a value from the dropdown list, it should search through all the records and find only records with the ddl value in them.

The code that I am using in the codebehind for the SelectedIndexChanged is not right though. I get an error message saying `'Value' is not a member of 'Integer'.` This is on the line `dsCompanyFilter.SelectParameters.Add`

It probably has something to do with the gridview not tying to the dropdown list properly, but I am not sure how to fix that code. Please help!

```
  <asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="body" Runat="Server"><br /><br /><br />
<asp:linkbutton id="btnAll" runat="server" text="ALL" onclick="btnAll_Click" />
<asp:repeater id="rptLetters" runat="server" datasourceid="dsLetters">
<headertemplate>
 |
</headertemplate>
<itemtemplate>
 <asp:linkbutton id="btnLetter" runat="server" onclick="btnLetter_Click" 
 text='<%#Eval("Letter")%>' />
 </itemtemplate>

<separatortemplate>
 |
</separatortemplate>
</asp:repeater>

<asp:sqldatasource id="dsLetters" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$ 
 ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>"
 selectcommand="SELECT DISTINCT LEFT(ProductName, 1) AS [Letter] FROM [Product]">
</asp:sqldatasource>

Filter By Company:<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlCompany" runat="server" 
DataSourceID="dsCompanyFilter"  DataTextField="CompanyName" DataValueField="CompanyID">
</asp:DropDownList>
<asp:gridview id="gvProducts" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
datakeynames="ProductID" datasourceid="dsProductLookup" 
style="margin-top: 12px;">
<Columns>
     <asp:BoundField DataField="ProductName" HeaderText="ProductName" 
     SortExpression="ProductName" />
</Columns>

</asp:gridview>

<asp:sqldatasource id="dsProductLookup" runat="server" connectionstring="<%$  
ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>"
Selectcommand="SELECT ProductID, ProductName FROM [Product] ORDER BY [ProductName]">
 </asp:sqldatasource>

<asp:SqlDataSource ID="dsCompanyFilter" runat="server" 
    ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ProductsConnectionString %>" 
    SelectCommand="SELECT [CompanyName], [CompanyID] FROM [Company]">
</asp:SqlDataSource>

</asp:Content>
```

This code filters the results in the gridview by Letter and the Dropdown. The problem is with the dropdown list filtering the gridview.

```
 Protected Sub btnLetter_Click(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
    Dim btnLetter As LinkButton = TryCast(sender, LinkButton)
    If btnLetter Is Nothing Then
        Return
    End If
    dsProductLookup.SelectCommand = [String].Format("SELECT ProductID, ProductName 
                                                   FROM [Product] 
                                                   WHERE ([ProductName] LIKE '{0}%') 
                                                   ORDER BY [ProductName]", btnLetter.Text)
 End Sub
```

This is the part that has the problem. I now get the error, must declare the scalar variable @CompanyID

```
Protected Sub ddlCompany_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As 
System.EventArgs) Handles ddlCompany.SelectedIndexChanged
    dsProductLookup.SelectCommand = "SELECT ProductName, CompanyID, CompanyName 
                                     FROM Product, Company 
                                     WHERE CompanyID = @CompanyID 
                                     ORDER BY ProductName"
    dsProductLookup.SelectParameters.Add("@CompanyID", DbType.Int32, 
    ddlCompany.SelectedValue)
End Sub
```

Comment: Are you fully populating the grid first and then filtering, not populating until a filter is selected or are you populating on a default filter first?

Comment: The gridview is already populated when I pull up the page. Then a user will be able to click on the dropdown list and choose a value to re-populate the gridview

Comment: I would look into filtering your data object instead of requerying the database. If it's just to view and not edit there's no point to talk to the database again unless it's to check for new records. Linq is awesome to query data objects (collections, datasets, etc) to filter by a particular value. Querying the database just to filter results you already have will be a lot slower than populating from the data you grabbed initially. You can always update the database from the data object after.

Comment: That makes sense. All the products are already listed in the gridview. I've never used Linq before but I hear good things.

Comment: It's not very difficult to do something like that. Check it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Deleted my previous answer.

Actually try the following :

```
dsProductLookup.SelectParameters.Add("@ProductID",
    DbType.Int32, ddlCompany.SelectedValue)
```

No assignment to value as it is part of the `Add`.  Noticed this when I tried to compile a test of my previous answer which didn't work.

**EDIT**: I tried the above code and it worked (did it in C#) but changed it to use `DbType.Int32` for second param.

Comment: This code threw an error in Visual Studio saying something about an overload resolution.

Comment: `Overload resolution failed because no accessible 'Add' can be called without a narrowing conversion: 'Public Function Add(name As String, dbType As System.Data.DbType, value As String) As Integer': Argument matching parameter 'dbType' narrows from 'System.Data.SqlDbType' to 'System.Data.DbType'.`

`Public Function Add(name As String, type As System.TypeCode, value As String) As Integer: Argument matching parameter 'type' narrows from 'System.Data.SqlDbType' to System.TypeCode.`

Comment: @jlg see my change it should address the problem.

Comment: Ok that worked, there are no more errors. But the dropdown list doesn't filter the gridview and now the links inside the gridview don't work.

Comment: @jlg this is getting tiring... I don't use SqlDataSources so I could be off but do you not have to rebind your grid to reflect the changes or trigger your DataSource to refresh?

Comment: @Kelsey Be nice. He's looking for help. If you can't or don't want to, you can politely say so.

Comment: @jlg step through and see what this value is: ddlCompany.SelectedValue. that's the value you're passing into your parameter. If that's what it should be, then you'll have to rebind your dataobject as Kelsey suggested.

Comment: @Yatrix I didn't even notice you called me a guy! I'm the girl graduating in my profile pic. I know it's a little small to see me haha. I edited the original post, I now have a new error

Comment: @jlg Sorry about that. I forgot girls can be programmers, drive cars and vote and stuff now. Love this country: we're all equal in our right to be a nerd. =) If you are getting a new error and your original issue is resolved, you should accept a correct answer here (if you found one) and post a new question. This one is getting pretty cluttered. Also, make sure to see if you can figure the error out on your own - it's the best way to learn. We're always happy to help, though.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing here -- I don't use `SqlDataSource`s -- but it looks like `SelectParameters.Add` takes three parameters. What happens when change this:

```
dsProductLookup.SelectParameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = ddlCompany.SelectedValue
```

to this:

```
dsProductLookup.SelectParameters.Add("@ProductID", DbType.Int32, ddlCompany.SelectedValue)
```

or this:

```
dsProductLookup.SelectParameters.Add("@ProductID", TypeCode.Int32, ddlCompany.SelectedValue)
```

Comment: This code threw an error in Visual Studio saying something about an overload resolution.

Comment: @jlg, I've edited the answer above to show you the enum options here. This information is also available on MSDN here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491445.aspx

Answer (score 0):

```
dsProductLookup.SelectParameters.Add("@ProductID", SqlDbType.Int).Value
```

It looks to me ilke the .Add() method is returning an int, to which .Value is not a property.

Confirmed it to make sure: 
[image]

This is from the MSDN: Should help.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w1kdt8w2.aspx

Comment: Yeah that is what Visual Studio is telling me. I'm just not sure what to do here. I've never tried filtering a gridview this way.

Comment: Ah, I thought you were confused why you were getting the error. =)

Comment: Oh :) I was just hoping someone might've had experience with this error and be willing to help me understand what I am doing wrong.